# How to display remaining available spots for an event on the public page

Tags: civievent

We need to display how many spots are left for registration on the public event registration page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done this already - I recommend customising the template. I have experience of doing this. You'll want to create a templates override file, and then embed some PHP that accesses the remaining places. It's fairly straightforward. If you want me to go into more details then please message me!

Comment: That would be great, we're definitely interested. How do I message you on this forum?

Comment: Email me at john@civifirst.com and I'll get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

There was an old recipe at https://civicrm.org/blog/chrischinchilla/displaying-remaining-participant-slots-on-events saying

```
{crmAPI var="ParticipantS" entity="Participant" action="get" sequential="1" event_id=$event.id }
// Gets the current particiapnst registered for the event

{* $x=$event.max_participants, $y=$ParticipantS.count *}
// Assigns our variables for the calculation below

Remaining - {math equation="x - y" x=$event.max_participants y=$ParticipantS.count}
// Subtract the current particpants from the maximum.
```